# python webdriver will not run if called from php

Tags: php, python-2.7

I am trying to execute my python script from php.  It stops working at the line where the webdriver is called [pytest.py]:

```
path_to_chromedriver = '/home/user/Desktop/2014/programs/chromedriver/chromedriver' # change path as needed
#i can print out something here (e.g. print 'hello') but not after the next line
br = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
```

And this is how PHP is calling the python script [phptest.php]:

```
$eventid_arg = $_REQUEST['eventid'];
$pyresponse_str = system("python pytest.py $eventid_arg", $retval);
```

Comment: Does the user have necessary permissions to run the python webdriver?

Comment: The permissions are fine.